# Typo3 image editing plugin

Tags: typo3

Is there any image editing plugin like [ed_pixlr](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ed_pixlr/current/) that works with a current version of typo3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me in 4.6.4.

The only thing I noticed was that the extension configuration didn't automatically enable the module in `TSconfig`. Add these lines in the `User TSconfig`:

```
tx_edpixlr = 1
tx_edpixlr.rendertype = editor
```

Or add these lines in `ext_tables.php`:

```
t3lib_extMgm::addUserTSConfig('tx_edpixlr=1');
t3lib_extMgm::addUserTSConfig('tx_edpixlr.rendertype=editor');
```

To enable it by default.